# Spark performance in single node

Tags: apache-spark

Im trying to execute some of the sample Python - Scikit scripts into Spark in Single node (my desktop - Mac - 8 GB). Here is my configuration
spark-env.sh file.

```
SPARK_MASTER_HOST='IP'
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=3
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
```

Im starting my slaves

```
./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://IP
```

Workers Table in (http://localhost:8080/) shows there are 3 workers running with each 2 cores

My script file which I took it from (https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/08/auto-scaling-scikit-learn-with-apache-spark.html)

```
from sklearn import svm, grid_search, datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from spark_sklearn.util import createLocalSparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate()
digits = datasets.load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target

param_grid = {"max_depth": [3, None],
              "max_features": [1, 3, 10],
              "min_samples_split": [2, 3, 10],
              "min_samples_leaf": [1, 3, 10],
              "bootstrap": [True, False],
              "criterion": ["gini", "entropy"],
              "n_estimators": [10, 20, 40, 80]}
gs = GridSearchCV(sc,RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid=param_grid)
gs.fit(X, y)
```

Submitting the script

```
spark-submit --master spark://IP traingrid.py
```

However I do not see any significant improvement in the execution time. 
Is there any other configurations required to make it more parallel? Or I should add another node to improve it?

Comment: Since you anyway have only one machine - why don't you use `--master local[*]`?

Comment: You have around 900 combinations times the complexity of your model construction and training

Comment: How fast do you expect it to be ?